# Nested If then statements in Java (Basic)

Tags: java

I'm having problems with the if then statemenT. I'm making a program that will tell the user the grade if he enters a integer, ex A if he gets 100. The problem with this program is that if I input 50, It will print both the F and D mark. I have a feeling its my bracket that are the  culprit. If you can  help, it would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoanQualificationProgram{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int grade;
      grade = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (grade >=80) 
        System.out.println("Your grade is an A");
      else {
        if (grade >=70)
           System.out.println("Your grade is B");
        else {
          if (grade>=60)
             System.out.println("your grade is a C");
          else {
             if (grade >=50)
                System.out.println("your grade is a D");
             if (grade >=0)
                System.out.println("your grade is an F");
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: You simply forgot the else after the condition checking for greater than 50.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to nest these statements. To use `else-if` effectively, try something like this:

```
if (grade >=80) {
  // A...
}
else if (grade >=70) {
  // B...
}
else if (grade>=60) {
  // C...
}
// ...
else {
  // Finally...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this bro or use case statement :)

```
if (grade >=80) 
  System.out.println("Your grade is an A");
else if(grade >=70)
    System.out.println("Your grade is B");
else if (grade>=60)
      System.out.println("your grade is a C");
else if (grade >=50)
        System.out.println("your grade is a D");
else if(grade >=0)
        System.out.println("your grade is an F");
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax error in your code. `else (grade >=0)` is not valid Java.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt i add "if" on the last statement.. try it i think that cause the problem